# Are we replacing, or augmenting the mods with this election?

Tags: discussion, election

So perhaps this is a dumb question (wouldn't be the first time), but I guess I was under the impression that the mods we're in the process of electing would be *augmenting* those that we already have, not replacing them. Is that not the case? I was thinking about running, but not if it means potentially bumping one of the folks we have now, who are doing a great job...

Answer (score 8):

[This site](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/stack-exchange-2011-elections-begin/), a post from Jeff, answers it as thus:

> However, in the spirit of fairness and
>   representative democracy, pro tem
>   moderators must run for election if
>   they wish to continue on as community
>   moderators.

Answer (score 1):

It's replacing. It's a feature of the Stack site to vote in moderators annually. Our little site is still small, so the available slots are small, but this will grow in time. However, by all means run. I think you'll find that the existing mods will welcome that, though I too agree with your assessment.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. Personally I don't feel especially qualified to be a moderator, but maybe at some point down the line I'll feel differently...

Comment: I for one, agree with Joanne. I won't speak for the others, but as a current moderator I welcome others to run. I enjoy being able to help run the site, but if the community felt that someone else would do a better job or was more deserving in some way, I'm all for that.  As long as the community is in good hands I'll be happy. :)